# What does this mean: &**this;

Tags: c++

I recently saw this in an iterator class code

```
pointer operator->() {
  return &**this;
}
```

Can someone please explain how does this work.

Comment: One probably should be using `std::addressof(**this)`

Answer (score 3):

`this` is a pointer to the iterator class. `*this` is the iterator itself. `**this` is the result of invoking `this->operator*()` - presumably, a reference to an element in the underlying container. `&**this` is then a (raw, dumb) pointer to said element.